# Kusto Query JSON Array Values

Tags: kql, azure-information-protection

can anyone offer a clue on how to do query values within arrays -- such as below, I want to find all records where

`DiscoveredInformationTypes_s Confidence > 80`

Can anyone help? How do I query inside this array?

```
MachineName_s
Version_s
ProcessName_s
ApplicationName_s
Operation_s
ObjectId_s
DiscoveredInformationTypes_s
[ { "Confidence": 55, "Count": 1, "SensitiveType": "3356946c-6bb7-449b-b253-6ffa419c0ce7", "UniqueCount": 1, "SensitiveInformationDetections": null, "Name": "International Classification of Diseases (ICD-10-CM)" } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mv-apply`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator

for example:

```
datatable(DiscoveredInformationTypes_s:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([ { "Confidence": 55, "Count": 1, "SensitiveType": "3356946c-6bb7-449b-b253-6ffa419c0ce7", "UniqueCount": 1, "SensitiveInformationDetections": null, "Name": "International Classification of Diseases (ICD-10-CM)" } ]),
    dynamic([ { "Confidence": 81, "Count": 1, "SensitiveType": "3356946c-6bb7-449b-b253-6ffa419c0ce7", "UniqueCount": 1, "SensitiveInformationDetections": null, "Name": "International Classification of Diseases (ICD-10-CM)" } ])
]
| mv-apply DiscoveredInformationTypes_s on (
    where DiscoveredInformationTypes_s.Confidence > 80
)
```

or, if your column is `string`-typed and not `dynamic`-typed, you'll need to invoke `parse_json()` on it first:

```
datatable(s:string)
[
    '[ { "Confidence": 55, "Count": 1, "SensitiveType": "3356946c-6bb7-449b-b253-6ffa419c0ce7", "UniqueCount": 1, "SensitiveInformationDetections": null, "Name": "International Classification of Diseases (ICD-10-CM)" } ]',
    '[ { "Confidence": 81, "Count": 1, "SensitiveType": "3356946c-6bb7-449b-b253-6ffa419c0ce7", "UniqueCount": 1, "SensitiveInformationDetections": null, "Name": "International Classification of Diseases (ICD-10-CM)" } ]'
]
| project DiscoveredInformationTypes_s = parse_json(s)
| mv-apply DiscoveredInformationTypes_s on (
    where DiscoveredInformationTypes_s.Confidence > 80
)
```

Comment: Hi Yoni, not really sure I understand. 

What is the (d:dynamic) and the other "dynamic"? 

Sorry to sound a bit dumb, but I also dont understand what the "d on" is? What does mv-apply mean?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work...

InformationProtectionLogs_CL
| mv-apply DiscoveredInformationTypes_s on (where DiscoveredInformationTypes_s.Confidence > 80)

Comment: if `DiscoveredInformationTypes_s` is a `string` and not a `dynamic` column, you'll need to first make it `dynamic` (e.g. by invoking `parse_json()` on it)

Comment: Hi, sorry, but its not that its a string, I dont understand why you have used "d" .. what is d? Ive looked at the syntax on that MS page and I dont understand the terms. Why is there not a simple way just to query the value of one of these list pairs? :( This seems far more complex than needed. Dont get it.

Comment: `d` is just a name of a `dynamic-typed` column in the example (i've now renamed it to match your original column name - `DiscoveredInformationTypes_s is`, if that helps). i'm using an inline `datatable` for the sake of providing you with a reproducible example/query, as obviously *only you* have access to *your* table

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out in the end. Im new to this stuff :)